# c# meaning of ! before a statement

Tags: c#, .net, logical-operators, negation

i am writing an application someone could help me with just giving me sample code ! 
i'm stuck in this place ! any one have any ideas ?

```
bool bl = false;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
bl = !reader.ReadToEnd().Contains("auto_load_more_enabled");
if (reader.ReadToEnd().Contains("wait"))
{
    bl = true;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-

Comment: If you mean `!`, then it basically translates to `not`. So if you place this before your boolean expression, it will return true only if the conditions of the expression are not met.

Comment: if it says bl = false it means reader contains("auto_load_more_enabled") ??

Comment: @MdSalehGh yes that is correct

Comment: @canton7 Thanks a lot mate ! appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!` is the NOT (negation) logical operator.

It transform a false to true and true to false.

[Boolean logical operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a `negation operator`, the `!` placed in from of a boolean expression inverse the result.

You can see more on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)